# How to Capture "F2" key in asp.net web forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

In my web application I want to open a new page when user presses <kbd>F2</kbd> key.

I found that it is possible with Java script, so I write some code in Java script but it is only working in Firefox, It is not working in Ie or Chrome.

Can some body please check?

Many Thanks

```
    <body onkeypress="onkeydown(event)" >

    <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       function onkeydown(e) {
            var intKey;
            if(window.event)
            {   
                intKey  = e.keycode     

            }
            else 
            {               
                intKey = e.which;
            }         

          if(intKey == 113)
          {
             window.open("HelpFile/index.html");
          }           

        }
    </script>
```

**Working code**:

```
    <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    document.onkeydown = function(event){
    if(window.event && window.event.keyCode == 113)
    {
        window.open("HelpFile/index.html");
    }
    else if(event.which == 113)
    {
         window.open("HelpFile/index.html");
    }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's `keyCode`, not `keycode` (note the uppercase C).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.onkeydown = function(){
if(window.event && window.event.keyCode == 122) 
{
alert(window.event.keyCode + " is pressed");
}
```

Comment: Hi henry, this is working in Ie and chrome but it has stopped working in Firefox. since window.event is not an known event in firefox. If i use both the code ( ur's and mine) then its working fine. but for some reason ie is throwing an error **object doesnt support this property or method**.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using jQuery, use jQuery:

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    var f2Key = 113;
    if (event.which == f2Key) {
        alert('you pressed F2');
    }
});
```

And I find it helpful to document magic numbers such as `113` by using a well-named variable like `f2Key`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `e.keyCode` and not `e.keycode`.